# I can't upload pdf files in php

Tags: php, pdf, upload

Now i am trying to upload pdf files by the form in php but when i upload it, it doesn't work because function `is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])` return false

How can i solve it please ?? 
I am using localhost and I verify php.ini

```
; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
upload_tmp_dir = "E:/wamp/tmp"

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

This is my code :

**Class**

```
<?php

require '../includes/master.inc.php';
// Kick-out users who aren't logged in as an admin
$auth->requireAdmin('../login_admin_cp.php');
if (isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])) {
    $error->blank($_POST['field_name'], "field_name");
    if ($error->ok()) {   

        $field_name = $_POST['field_name'];        
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
//            exit;
            $mypath = "upload/";
            $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $n = $mypath . $file_name;            
            $t = $_FILES['file']['size'];
            $filesize = round($t / 1024) . " KB";
            $extintion = strchr($n, ".");
            $extintion = strtolower($extintion);
            $file_extintion_allow = array(".pdf");
            if ($n == "") {
                echo "Error in upload";
            } elseif (!in_array($extintion, $file_extintion_allow)) {
                echo "من فضلك ادخل المادة بطريقة صحيحة";
                exit;
            } else {
                //rename the file when upload by query name
                $quaryname = rand(11111, 99999);
                $rename = "../" . $mypath . $quaryname . $extintion;
                $URL = substr($rename, 10, strlen($rename));
                move_uploaded_file($tmp, $rename);
                if (!empty($_POST['hide'])) {
                    $hide = $_POST['hide'];
                    $db->query("insert into field (field_name,url,hide)values('$field_name','$URL','$hide')");
                    $sess->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'تم  حفظ المادة بنجاح');
                    redirect("field_new.php");
                } else {
                    $db->query("insert into field (field_name,url,hide)values('$field_name','$URL','0')");
                    $sess->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'تم  حفظ المادة بنجاح');
                    redirect("field_new.php");
                }
            }
        } else {
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        $sess->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'حقل المادة فارغ');
    }
}

// View 
include('views/header.php');
include('views/field_form_new.php');
include('views/footer.php');
?>
```

**Form**

```
<!-- Form elements -->    
<div class="grid_9">
    <div class="module">
         <h2><span>  رفع المادة</span></h2>
         <div class="module-body">
                <?php echo $error;?>
           <form action="field_new.php" method="post"  name="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">

             <p>
                <label> اسم المادة</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-medium" name="field_name" value="" />
            </p>             
            <p  style="font-size:14px"> رفع المادة </p> 
            <p>
                <label> الرابط</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-medium" name="link" value="<?php  $link; ?>" />
            </p> 
            أو<br/> <br/>            

              <p>
              <input type="hidden" class="input-medium" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000"> 
              <label>رفع الملف   </label>
              <input  type="file"  class="input-medium" name="file" />
             </p>   
             <p>

              <input type="checkbox"  name="hide" value="1"   />تفعيل المادة
             </p>

            <fieldset>
                <input  class="submit-green" type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="اضافة"  /> 
            </fieldset>
        </form>
     </div> <!-- End .module-body -->
    </div>  <!-- End .module -->
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div> <!-- End .grid_6 -->
```

Comment: What is the size of the file you are uploading?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the file is to big or the destination directory is not writeable for php/apache.

Check the folder permission `"E:/wamp/tmp"` and try to upload a smaller file.

If a smaller file works, check these values in the php.ini file:

```
post_max_size
max_input_time
memory_limit
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i had only changed the upload_max_filesize = 50M entry in php.ini file.  after setting post_max_size = 50M  it works..